# How to abort RequireJS 'require' request?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, deferred

Is it possible (and how) to abort RequireJS `require` request?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
define([
    'Backbone.View'
],
function (BackboneView) {

    var View = BackboneView.extend({

        initialize: function () {

            // store require deferred
            // (I know this is not possible in this way!)
            // Is there a way to capture require deferred?

            this.deferred = require(['someModule'], function () {

                // do something

            });

        },

        close: function () {

            // abort require request if view is closed before request resolves
            this.deferred.abort();

            this.remove()

        }

    });

    return View;

});
```

So, I want to be able to abort `require` request if Backbone View is closed before `require` request resolves.

I have checked RequireJS documentation and their GitHub page.
There is nothing describing how to handle this.

Any help is welcome :)
Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequireJS does not provide a means to cancel a `require` call.

I suppose in theory it would be possible to implement it but it would complicate RequireJS' internal by *a lot* for rather rare benefits. Suppose you require `foo`, consider:

1. How often will your code *actually* be in a position where cancelling the `require` call is desirable? Your view would have to be initialized and closed in quick succession.
2. If `foo` has already been fetched and initialized before the `require` call is issued the *only* job `require` has to do is return the already existing reference to `foo`. So there is essentially nothing to cancel. Note here that if the view is ever allowed to completely initialize even *just once* in your application, the scenario considered here applies.
3. If RequireJS was fast enough to complete the `require` call before cancellation, then cancellation has no effect. Once an application is optimized, it is quite likely that RequireJS will complete the call before cancellation is possible. In an optimized app, the code that runs `require` is in the same bundle as the code being required, so RequireJS does no have to fetch anything from the network to satisfy the `require` call.

So in many cases the cancellation would be without effect, but for the cases where RequireJS might have to cancel something, it would have to keep a close accounting of who is requiring what. Maybe your `require` call in your view is the only one that is requiring `foo` but `foo` may also be requiring `bar` and `baz`. If `foo` is the only one requiring them, then if you cancel the `require` call, then RequireJS can cancel fetching and initializing `foo`, `bar` and `baz` but there's always the possibility that *after* the `require` is issued but *before* it completes *another* part of your application needs `baz`. So now RequireJS has to remember that it is okay to cancel `foo` and `bar` but **not** `baz` because it was required somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I must admit that I didn't look at it that way but you are right. Do you suggest to run optimization (r.js) for all modules and files or just for some and leave other to be dynamically loaded?

Comment: You're welcome. Whether to bundle everything in one file or have multiple bundles really depends on the details of your application. In very many cases, bundling everything into one file is the way to go. However, if you have an application with optional plugins, there's no good reason to bundle everything together, especially if the plugins are substantial. In this case, a core bundle plus one bundle per plugin is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little weird seeing you will deploy only one minimised file and there will be virtually no delay.

For science note that a require simply adds a script element to the DOM with certain proporties like `data-requiremodule=[MODULE_NAME]`
 so you can basically do something like:

```
function abortModuleLoad(moduleName)
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for(var i = 0 ; i < scripts.length ; i++){
        if(scripts[i].dataset.requiremodule === moduleName) document.head.removeChild(scripts[i])
    }
}

close: function () {

    // abort require request if view is closed before request resolves
    abortModuleLoad("someModule");

    this.remove()

}
```

Comment: Did you test this? Do you know that removing the `script` elements that are added by RequireJS won't actually cause RequireJS to get into an inconsistent state?

Comment: Hi raam86, thank you for your answer.
The thing is that I don't want to run r.js. So scripts won't be minified to one file. Some files should be loaded just in some cases.
Also, before creating script tag in head file script source should be loaded dynamically. This action I want to abort if view is closed and request is not resolved yet.